# mat-button set disabled using an attribute directive?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have an attribute directive called userPermission, that is supposed to do some logic and then set the disabled attribute to the element it is attached.
`<button userPermission>Disable me with userPermission</button>`

```
<button color="primary" (click)="onNewConfiguration()" userPermission>Add Configuration</button>
<button color="primary" mat-raised-button (click)="onNewConfiguration()" userPermission>Add Configuration</button>
```

the `mat-raised-button` does not work with `ElementRef`, or `Renderer2`

I can not use `<button mat-raised-button [disabled]="someVar"></button>`

I have to use an attribute directive.
and I have tried

```
this.el.nativeElement.disabled = true;
this.renderer.setAttribute(this.el.nativeElement, 'disabled', 'disabled');
this.el.nativeElement.setAttribute("disabled", "true");
```

None of these techniques worked.

How can you set a mat-button to disabled using an attribute directive?

Comment: Wow thanks for all the replies guys, I am a bit too busy to test any of these at the moment, but ill try to get to it eventually!

Answer (score 3):

Use template ref to disable the Button dynamically or
Another Way is use ViewChild to get ref to the button then set _disable to tru

```
 @ViewChild('ref2') ref2;
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="button-row">
  <button #ref mat-raised-button (click)="onNewConfiguration(ref)">Basic</button>
```

**TS**

set _disabled property true to disable button

```
 onNewConfiguration(ref){
    ref._disabled=true;
  }
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zdcz25

Comment: Does @ViewChild work with the logic of an Attribute Directive?

Comment: #ref  which means template reference and ViewChild is decorator which is use to get ref of the element

Comment: ref._disabled=true; is worked for me. I have searched many solutions. This is easy and best one. worked for me in Angular 8

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of research, I found a solution for this. Though this is very late to answer but might be useful for someone else. I made it work by adding a class with styles as follows:

```
.disable-ctrl {

  pointer-events: none !important;

}
```

Then added above class in directives native element as follows:

```
this.renderer.addClass(this.el.nativeElement, "disable-ctrl");
```

With this I was able to disable all the controls in my app by using directive.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.el.nativeElement.disabled = true;
```

works for me.

see https://angular-rb5vmu.stackblitz.io, in the Get Data button there is a directive: spinnerButton, that receives a value (boolean) to change button text and disable it.

Comment: `<button userPermission>Disable me with userPermission</button>`

are you using an attribute directive though?

Answer (score 0):

Modify directly the DOM in Angular 6 with

> `this.elem.nativeElement.querySelector(".button-row").xxx = 'yyy';`

is an **security issue.  Do not do it**.

You have to do with render2 object. That way:

> `this.render2.setProperty(this.elem.nativeElement.querySelector(".button-row"),'xxx', 'yyy');`

That way
To disable your button:

> `this.render2.setProperty(this.elem.nativeElement.querySelector(".button-row"),'disabled', 'true');`

The value can be any other like 'disabled', 'x', 'freedom!', 'anything', 'false', etc

To enable your button:

> `this.render2.setProperty(this.elem.nativeElement.querySelector(".button-row"),'disabled', '');`

The value just have to be empty.

Comment: You can access the Dom with this.elem.nativeElement.querySelector(".button-row") this is not an security issue.  This is use in readonly and render2 in write context.

Answer (score 0):

we can simply do this

```
<button mat-button #matRef (click)="buttonMat(matRef)"></button>

buttonMat(matRef) {
    matRef.disabled=true;
}
```